# Müssen auch Muttersprachler die Artikel der Nomen lernen?

Tags: gender

Das ist eine auf einem Missverständnis basierende, kurze Frage.

Man hört viel zu oft, *Deutschlerner* müssen die Genera jedes Nomens lernen. Das ist unbestritten. Ich frage mich aber nun, ob Muttersprachler es auch müssen, d. h., ob sie aufgrund eines angeborenen Sprachgefühls die Artikel eines neuen Substantivs erraten können oder es auch lernen müssen. Schlagt ihr als Muttersprachler gelegentlich in einem Wörterbuch nach, um das Genus zu erfahren?

(Je nachdem sollten auch Deutschlerner das Gefühl entwickeln, Genera erraten zu können?)

Comment: Die Diskussion um "Die/das Nutella" oder "der/das Yoghurt" beantwortet die Frage, oder?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Nein, "Nutella" und "Jogurt" ist ein ganz anderes Paar Schuhe. In beiden Fällen gibt es – je nachdem wo man genau lebt – sowieso eine andere "richtige" Antwort. Jogurt kann je nach Region zum Beispiel auch 'weiblich' sein. Ich habe aber für diese beiden Wörter noch nie ein Dictionary zu Rate ziehen müssen und kann dir so sagen: Es ist **die** Nutella und **der** Jogurt. Da werden mir aber nicht alle Deutschen zu stimmen.

Comment: Hey, "die Joghurt" (im Deutschen mit J) gibt es auch noch, siehe [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Joghurt)

Comment: @Em1 Ich finde nicht, dass das was anderes ist. Es geht mir darum, dass auch bei Muttersprachlern manchmal keine Sicherheit besteht, welcher Artikel zu verwenden ist. Wenn es dich aber glücklicher macht, nehmen wir "Zölibat" als beispiel und dann googeln wir mal, wie oft die Frage "Heißt es der oder das Zölibat" auftaucht. Wir müssen die Artikel meist zwar nicht lernen (weil wir sie für die meisten Wörter im Zuge des Spracherwerbs lernen), aber es gibt eben Wörter, für die das nicht so klar ist und wo auch wir nachschauen müssen.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar auch ein Muttersprachler ist nicht allwissend. Wie Magellan88 schon erwähnt hat, gibt es allerdings gewisse Regeln, die durch den Gebrauch der Sprache erlernt werden.

Comment: @Pasoe Sage ich doch! Und genau das ist doch die Antwort auf die Frage: Ja, auch wir Muttersprachler müssen manchmal nachschauen. Übrigens: Dass Deutschlerer das Genus jedes Wortes lernen müssen ist quatsch. Das weiß ich aus Erfahrung.

Comment: Du musst sie nicht lernen. Du musst sie nur wissen ;)
 Das tun Muttersprachler für die meisten. Wenn nicht, wird nachgeguckt (Journalisten werden das wohl mal tun) und dann wissen sie es das nächste mal.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar In deinem Kommentar fehlt im Wort "Deutschlerer" ein Buchstabe. Falls du den Deutschlehrer (also den der andere unterrichtet) gemeint hast, kann ich dir zumindest teilweise zustimmen. In der Frage war aber vom Deutschlerner die Rede, als von der Person, die gerade Deutsch lernt.

Comment: Sorry, blöder Schreibfehler. Natürlich meinte ich den "Deutschlehrer".

Comment: Ich denke der Klassiker wäre dann wohl 'Lineal' - war es jetzt der Lineal oder das Lineal?

Comment: a) Was soll das heißen: "eine auf ein Mißverständnis basierte Frage"? b) Was soll das sein, ein angeborenes  Sprachsgefühl? Ich behaupte sowas gibt es nicht und erbitte Belege für das Gegenteil. Was ist die Frage des letzten Satzes?

Answer (score 12):

Ja und nein. Die Mehrzahl der Artikel lernt man im Rahmen des regulären Spracherwerbs. Wenn Kinder Fehler machen, werden sie (hoffentlich) korrigiert, und merken sich das; soweit nichts Besonderes.

Bei neuen, oder unbekannten, Worten ist das aber nicht so. Oftmals steht auch (noch) gar nicht fest, welchen Artikel ein Wort bekommt; bisweilen ist das auch im deutschen Sprachraum nicht eindeutig: Wir Österreicher tendieren oftmals zu „das“, wo die Deutschen gerne „die“ benutzen (das/die Cola, das/die E-Mail). Im Zweifelsfall werden auch Muttersprachler im Wörterbuch nachschlagen, selbstverständlich.

Auch bei fachsprachlichen Begriffen gibt es bisweilen Unterschiede, manchmal ändert sich mit dem Artikel auch die Bedeutung (der/die/das Band). Also, alles nicht so einfach :)

Comment: Mir fällt noch eine weitere Gruppe ein, aus einer fremden Sprache übernommen Begriffe, wenn es in dieser Sprache ein grammatikalische Geschlecht gibt (zB Französisch). Wenn ich von einem französischen Bahnhof spreche, sage ich zB "die Gare du Nord" (la gare)? Oder "der Pont de Normandie" (le pont)? Was ist mit Mehrzahl, sage ich die/der/das "Champs Elysées" (Pl.)?

Comment: Kurze Anmerkung: Kinder lernen beim Spracherwerb gerade *nicht* durch korrigierenden Input („Das ist falsch, du musst ... sagen“), schlichtweg weil es nicht genug solchen Input gibt um die Gesamtheit der Grammatik einer Sprache daraus ableiten zu können. Vielmehr determinieren Kinder die Grammatik ihrer Muttersprache(n), und damit auch die Nominalklassen (d.h. Genus), beinahe ausschließlich aus dem expliziten Input, also aus dem, was sie während des Spracherwerbs hören.

Answer (score 9):

Magellan88 geht in seiner Antwort eigentlich schon auf einen wichtigen Punkt ein:

Als Kind machen wir viele Fehler. Dazu gehören die Artikel, aber auch beispielsweise falsche Konjugation.

> Ich habe gefliegt.

Kinder lernen mit der Zeit. Fehler werden direkt thematisiert

> Nein, es heißt "Ich bin geflogen".

oder die Kinder registrieren, dass alle anderen es immer anders sagen, und übernehmen dies mit der Zeit.

Im Laufe der Jahre bilden wir einen sehr großen Wortschatz und die korrekten Artikel sind dann irgendwann "ins Blut übergegangen". Die Schule hilft dabei auch noch signifikant. Dort wird das Thema ja auch mehr als nur einmal gelehrt. (Ich beziehe mich hier nicht auf die Bestimmung des Genus – das wird nicht gelehrt –, sondern vielmehr auf das Verstehen dessen, was die Artikel bedeuten, und auf die richtige Anwendung, hier einbegriffen die Deklination).

Dennoch lernen wir auch immer wieder neue Wörter. Ich kann nicht sagen, wo genau die Grenze ist; aber ab einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt, denke ich, sind wir (meistens) in der Lage, zu jedem neuen Wort den korrekten Artikel herzuleiten.

Es gibt eine Handvoll an Wörtern, für die das mit Sicherheit nicht gilt. Dies ist aber relativ unbedeutend.

Und ja, manchmal muss man nachschlagen. In aller Regel für Wörter, die man gar nicht kennt oder die man sehr selten benutzt (=Fremdwörter). Aber es gibt auch schon mal "Blackout-Momente", wo einem ein Wort auf einmal fremd ist oder eben der zugehörige Artikel.

---

Im Spanischen habt ihr ja letztlich auch das gleiche Problem. Im Falle von Wörtern wie "libro" ist es einfach (es endet auf "o"); aber ist es "el flor" oder "la flor"?! Und woher weißt du, dass es "el agua" ist, anstatt "la agua"? Wie oft hast du hier wohl als Kind den falschen Artikel verwendet?

Comment: Als kleine Bemekrung bedeutet *el agua* komischerweise nicht, dass *agua* männlich sei (das verstehst du vielleicht schon). Man sagt so, weil man da vermeiden will, zwei *a* nebeneinander, also eine Kakophonie vermeiden will (genau wie auf Fr. man *mon amie* anstelle *ma amie* sagen muss). Aber *agua* ist tatsächlich weiblich ;) (d.h., *el agua limpia* ← das Adj. ist in weiblicher Form.) Als Kind macht man eher Fehler mit Partizipien (*yo he hacido* anstelle *yo he hecho*). Genusfehler macht man, finde ich, auf Spanisch nicht so oft wie Konjugationsfehler.

Comment: @em1 das stimmt, aber im Spanischen ist das "natürliche" oder "biologische" Genus fast immer auch das grammatische Genus, also ist es einfacher, es zu erraten.

Comment: @karoshi Bestimmte bitte das biologische Geschlecht eines Löffels. Für mich ist es "sächlich", "neutrum". Im Deutschen jedoch "männlich", im Spanischen "weiblich".

Comment: @em1, ah, richtig, und die Tatsache, dass es im Spanischen kein sächliches Geschlecht gibt, macht es noch einfacher. Ich gebe zu, dass im Fall von Gegenständen gibt es keine Faustregel, aber zumindest gibt es eine in anderen Fällen. Im Deutschen gibt es keine Regel in dem einen und in den anderen.

Comment: Netürlich spreche ich nicht von abgeleiteten Substantiven.

Answer (score 8):

Aus eigener Erfahrung kann ich sagen, dass es nur sehr, sehr seltene Fälle gibt, in denen ich das Geschlecht nicht auf Anhieb sagen könnte (vielleicht so einmal im Jahr), und in diesen Fällen ist es oft auch nicht eindeutig oder regional unterschiedlich. Ich würde also sagen, dass Deutsch-Muttersprachler die Artikel ziemlich genau wissen.

Die wirklich interessante Frage ist, ob wir die Geschlechter lernen oder uns ableiten:
Falls wir sie ableiten, tun wir das unbewusst (was aber nicht heißt, dass wir es nicht tun). Mir und einer Gruppe anderer Muttersprachler wurde vor kurzem erklärt, dass alle Nomen, die auf -keit enden, weiblich seien. Wir haben alle nach Beispielen gesucht und erstaunt festgestellt, dass das zu stimmen scheint.

Andererseits habe ich vor kurzem im Sandkasten mit einem eigentlich sehr aufgeweckten Jungen gespielt (6 Jahre), der zu meiner Überraschung erstaunlich oft das falsche Geschlecht zu gewissen Nomen genutzt hat. Das muss mich anscheinend so sehr gestört haben, dass ich ihn doch einige Male korrigiert habe. Ich könnte mir also vorstellen, dass unser Sprachgefühl durch falsche Artikel so sehr gestört ist, dass wir unsere Kinder so lange korrigieren, bis sie es richtig gelernt haben.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn ein Kleinkind seine Muttersprache lernt, lernt es keine Regeln. Es hat keine Vorstellung von grammatikalischen Geschlechtern, weiß nichts von Beugung und kennt nicht mal die einfachsten Regeln für den Satzbau.

Mit der Zeit lernt es sprechen, so wie es auch gehen lernt. Fast kein Erwachsener kann einem anderen Erwachsenen detailliert erklären, wie man geht. Wir alle tun es, ohne uns über die genau aufeinander abgestimmte Reihenfolge der verschiedenen Muskelkontraktionen Gedanken zu machen. Die meisten von uns wissen nicht mal, wie die Muskeln heißen, die wir beim Gehen benutzen. Und trotzdem können wir es fast alle fast perfekt.

Auf ganz genau dieselbe Weise lernen Kinder auch ihre Muttersprache. An ihrem ersten Schultag können sie perfekt Fragesätze bilden. Konditionalsätze sind auch kein Problem, und dasselbe gilt im Fall von Sprachen mit Nominalklassen für die Zuordnung der Nomen zur richtigen Nominalklasse (Deutsch kennt die drei Nominalklassen "männlich", "weiblich" und "sächlich"; andere Sprachen wie z. B. Suaheli kennen bisweilen mehr als 20 solcher Kategorien.)

Deutschsprachige Muttersprachler lernen also die Artikel ebenso mühelos wie alles andere, was zu ihrer Sprache gehört, aber ohne dafür auch nur eine einzige Regel zu kennen. (Ungarische Schulanfänger beherrschen alle ca. 30 Fälle der ungarischen Sprache, ohne sich dessen bewusst zu sein, dass es so etwas wie Fälle überhaupt gibt.)

Da die Regeln für die Bestimmung des grammatischen Geschlechts auch nicht Teil des gewöhnlichen Deutschunterrichts sind, kann auch kaum jemand, der Deutsch als Muttersprache spricht, diese Regeln nennen. Oft sind wir Muttersprachler überrascht, wenn wir von einer solchen Regel hören und dann erstaunt feststellen, dass sie tatsächlich funktioniert. (Meist suchen wir dann minutenlang nach Ausnahmen, bis wir entweder triumphierend welche finden oder erstaunt und trotzdem zweifelnd die Regel zur Kenntnis nehmen.) 
Wenn wir erwachsen sind, müssen wir das, was wir als Kinder ganz nebenbei gemacht haben, wieder machen, wenn wir neue Wörter lernen. Wir müssen zu jedem neuen Nomen, das sich in unserem Wortschatz einnistet, den richtigen Artikel dazulernen. Und weil wir Muttersprachler (fast) keine Regeln zur Geschlechtsbestimmung kennen, können wir ohne Vorgabe nur raten, welcher Artikel richtig sein könnte.

### Nachtrag (Edit)

In diesem Zusammenhang (und ergänzend zur Antwort von Ingmar) ist auch erwähnenswert, dass die impliziten Regeln, nach denen wir Muttersprachler neuen Nomen einen Artikel zuweisen, nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum einheitlich sind. Während beispielsweise die Namen von Softdrinks und Zeitschriften in Deutschland weiblich sind ("die Cola", "die Fanta"; "die Bravo") sind diese Namen in Österreich allesamt sächlich ("das Cola", "das Fanta"; "das Bravo").

In weiterer Folge führt das dazu, dass es Nomen gibt, die mehrere Artikel haben können, weil in unterschiedlichen Regionen unterschiedliche Artikel vergeben wurden, die sich dann im Laufe der Zeit über den ganzen deutschen Sprachraum ausbreiten: "der/das Radio", "der/das Teller", "die/das E-Mail", "der/die Abscheu", "der/das Keks", "die/das Aspirin", "der/das Filter", "der/das Gummi", "der/die Paprika", "der/die Sellerie", "der/die Firewall", …

Answer (score -3):

The short answer is YES! Ja, müssen wir. :)

Comment: .............weil ? :)

Comment: Well what? The question was if natives have to learn these things by heart....YES, we do. I believe the question has been answered :)

Comment: it wasn't "well" it was "weil".

Comment: Whoops, sorry mate...I missed that :)      Because there ARE no rules for what we deem masculine and feminine; thus 'you need to learn it'  like every single German does as well. I thought I put that into my reply :)

Comment: That is not completely true. Yes, for basic lexemes you need to learn them (like any word), but at some point you can determine the gender of a noun. Composites, for instance, take their gender from the head noun. Derivation endings like *-lein* or *-chen*; or nominalized verbs imply the resulting noun to be of neuter gender, regardless of the stem noun's inherent gender, and so on. So there are some grammatical rules that specify the gender of a noun.