# »Sie lernt Gehen« oder »Sie lernt gehen«?

Tags: capitalization

Vor einiger Zeit schrieb ich als Antwort auf eine andere Frage dieses Forums den folgenden Satz (nämlich [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12027/m%C3%BCssen-auch-muttersprachler-die-artikel-der-nomen-lernen/12033#12033)):

> Mit der Zeit lernt es Sprechen, so wie es auch Gehen lernt.

(es = ein Kleinkind)

Heute wurden in diesem Satz die beiden Wörter »Gehen« und »Sprechen« zu »gehen« und »sprechen« korrigiert. Nach meinem Dafürhalten sind diese beiden Wörter aber Akkusativobjekte, also Substantive uns müssen daher groß geschrieben werden. Schließlich sind sie die Antwort auf die Frage: »Wen oder was lernt das Kind?«

Ist das denn falsch?
Falls die Kleinschreibung richtig sein sollte (was ich bezweifle): Welche grammatikalische Funktion haben »Gehen« und »Sprechen« in diesem Satz?

Comment: Ich glaube fast, beides ist richtig. Du kannst auf jeden Fall problemlos einen Artikel einfügen und damit wäre schon mal bewiesen, dass das Substantiv richtig ist. Aber auch als Verb kann man es hier durchgehen lassen, man lernt eben "sprechen" und nicht "das Sprechen".

Comment: Ich würde mich meinem Vorredner anschließen. Es kommt drauf an, wie man den Satz deuten will. `Mit der Zeit lernt es (das) Sprechen` ist eine Möglichkeit, eine weitere Möglichkeit ist `Mit der Zeit lernt es sprechen`. Hierbei wird "sprechen" als Verb verwendet. Auf Duden.de bin ich gerade auf das Beispiel mit sprechen kleingeschrieben gestoßen: [Link](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sprechen)

Comment: In case you (or other readers) are English speakers, I think we can think of this easier: With a capital S in Sprechen, it's like saying (made to sound better in English) "After some time he learns speaking". With a lower case, it's like "After some time he learns to speak".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laut *Duden – Die deutsche Rechtschreibung* schreibt man

> lieben lernen; schätzen lernen
>   wir haben ihn schätzen und lieben gelernt
>   rechnen, schwimmen, kochen lernen
>   *Vgl. aber* kennenlernen, kennen lernen

Laut *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* steht zusammen mit „lernen“ der Infinitiv.
Der Infinitiv steht im Allgemeinen ohne „zu“, wenn das Verb allein steht:

> Das Kind lernt sprechen.
>   Seine Frau lernt reiten.

Wenn das Verb nicht allein steht, kann auch der Infinitiv mit „zu“ stehen:

> Ich lernte die Maschine bedienen. Oder: Ich lernte[,] die Maschine zu bedienen.
>   Ich habe die Maschine bedienen gelernt. Oder: Ich habe die Maschine zu bedienen gelernt.
>   Ich lernte[,] die Maschine fachgerecht und effektiv zu bedienen.

Solche Verbindungen aus zwei Verben werden auch im amtlichen Regelwerk unter § 34 (4) aufgeführt. Die dort genannten Beispiele lauten:

> laufen lernen
>   arbeiten kommen
>   baden gehen
>   lesen üben

---

An anderer Stelle wird in *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erwähnt, dass oft nicht klar ist, ob es sich um einen verbalen Infinitiv (mit Kleinschreibung) oder um einen substantivierten Infinitiv (mit Großschreibung) handelt, wenn die Infinitive ohne Artikel oder nähere Bestimmung stehen. In solchen Fällen kann sowohl Groß- als auch Kleinschreibung gerechtfertigt sein.

> (…)
>   Emma lernt schwimmen / [das] Schwimmen.
>   (…)

Allerdings ist ein Infinitiv, der direkt von einem Modalverb abhängt, nicht substantiviert:

> Sie will Auto fahren.
>   Ich muss Briefe schreiben.
>   Möchtest du Eis essen? Ebenso: Sie sind essen gegangen.

Answer (score 5):

Das Österreichische Wörterbuch, 39. Auflage schreibt im Kapitel 1.2.1.1 dazu:

> **Bei manchen Infinitiven** (Nennformen) ist **Groß- und Kleinschreibung möglich**, weil man sie sowohl als nominales Satzglied als auch als Verb auffassen kann:
>
> *Sie übt Kopfrechnen/kopfrechnen (das Kopfrechnen/gut kopfrechnen). Er lernt Sprechen/sprechen (das Sprechen/zu sprechen). Es ist bekannt, dass Probieren/probieren über Studieren/studieren geht.*

Zumindest hier in Österreich sind also beide Formen zulässig, weil nicht klar ist, ob *zu + Infinitiv* oder *das + nominalisierter Infinitiv* gemeint ist.

Answer (score 2):

Laut Grammatikduden (§ 594) geht beides, teilweise auch zu-Infinitiv:

1. Die Kinder lernen rechnen/Rechnen. (Duden)
2. Die Kinder haben gelernt, mit Variablen zu rechnen.

Bei (1) halte ich zu-Infinitiv auch für möglich.

Ich denke, es kommt darauf an, was ich betonen will - will ich die Tätigkeit oder das Fach/die Fertigkeit in den Vordergrund rücken. Ich würde ohnehin den zu-Infinitiv bevorzugen.